# Biesemeyer style fence moves when locking it down

Tags: table-saw

My Grizzly table saw has a Biesemeyer style fence, When I set up and measure for a cut, as soon as I start tightening up the lock lever the fence moves to the right. If I leave the lock in this position and tap the fence hard back to the proper place and continue locking the lever it doesn't move. Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'll give it a try and see what happens thank you.

Comment: @Ashlar your comment seems sufficiently complete to be an Answer...

Comment: I believe your idea might be spot on, unfortunately I've been spraying in my workshop so haven't had a chance to check it out, at least now i know it's not a defect. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If Ashlar's answer addresses your question, don't forget to come back and mark the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Grizzly tablesaw with the same fence type. I find that when I adjust the fence it is not necessarily square when I move it to the desired dimension. I have to tighten the fence in place to get a fully accurate parallel setting for the fence and blade. Once I have set and unset the fence I can adjust it small amounts without appreciable changes in the angle. Could this be what you are experiencing?

Comment: This is how my SawStop T Glide fence works as well (it's pretty annoying...).